# How to find offending column? Can't Convert from string to int32

Tags: c#, .net, datatable, sqlbulkcopy

I am using SqlBulkCopy. So I made a datatable and specifed it's columns then added rows to the datatable and then try to insert it.

> System.InvalidOperationException was
>   unhandled by user code   Message=The
>   given value of type String from the
>   data source cannot be converted to
>   type int of the specified target

I keep getting this error though. The thing is I have 3 int columns and I have no clue which one it is.

I even put on each int column the type of of it.

```
 datatable.Columns.Add("Id", typeof(int));
```

Still seems to have problems. So where in the stack trace or int the exception will it say the actual column it dies on?

Comment: Do you have inner exception information available?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out Bruce Dunwiddie's excellent [ValidatingDataReader](http://www.csvreader.com/posts/validating_datareader.php) class.  It provides really excellent information in the exception messages when you have this kind of mapping issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can import the data into a table in SQL Server, and then you can use ISNUMERIC to see which is is:

```
SELECT *
  FROM YourImportTable
 WHERE ISNUMERIC(Column1) = 0
    OR ISNUMERIC(Column2) = 0
    OR ISNUMERIC(Column3) = 0
```

If you don't want to leave .NET, you can loop through the rows and try to convert them:

```
For Each dr as DataRow in datatable.Rows
   If Not IsNumeric(dr.Item(5))
      ' It's this column
   End If
   If Not IsNumeric(dr.Item(6))
      ' It's this column
   End If
Next
```

Comment: I found out it was a mapping problem.

Comment: So you no longer have an issue? Maybe indicate that in your question?